# How to prevent autofocus on textarea during first time creation in IE browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one button to create a `<textarea></textarea>`. When I click that button a new `<textarea>` will created. In Internet Explorer, whenever new `<textarea>` is created, cursor is placed in that textarea. I don't want the cursor to place on that newly created `<textarea>` element.

Comment: just do a blur or focus on someother object after it is created!
can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `blur()` function in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('body').append('<textarea>Text!!!</textarea>');
        $('body textarea:last-of-type').blur();
    });
});
```

Simple example. Appends a `<textarea>` to the body, then removes focus from it.

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bvL2cc8a/)

Answer (score 0):

just do a blur,focus-out or focus on someother object after it is created! 
Eg:
if the element you have created has a class "sample" then after creating do

```
$('textarea.sample').trigger('blur');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do trigger a blur event on the textarea using `.blur()` but actually the auto focus is not happening in IE.

Check this out http://jsbin.com/wijeya/1/